# Hosting multiple domains with WildFly (Undertow)

Tags: java, jboss, virtualhost, wildfly, undertow

For example I have two domains (**app1.com**, **app2.com**) and two ears (**app1.ear**, **app2.ear**). Each EAR file consists of ejb.jar and web.war. Also each WAR has context root: **/app1** or **/app2**.

So if I start WildFly I will have two applications running on **localhost:8080/app1** and **localhost:8080/app2**.

How I can bind **app1.com** to **localhost:8080/app1** and **app2.com** to **localhost:8080/app2**?

As I understand, I should modify Undertow subsystem configuration in standalone.xml. I tried:

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
    <host name="app1.com" default-web-module="app1.ear/web.war"/>
    <host name="app2.com" default-web-module="app2.ear/web.war"/>
</server>
```

but it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml

with contents

```
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>app1</context-root>
  <virtual-host>app1.com</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

and similarly for second war.

Comment: This dos not work for me. Only if I use URL http://app1.com/app1  . But how to configure if I like to acces the app1 from the root context  (http://app1.com) ?

Comment: then just set context-root to /

Comment: I tried but it did not work form me (using Wildfly 8.2)

Comment: Than please create new question and post your configuration so we can help you.